# How to create a YouTube playlist from a list of links?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have very long lists of YouTube links/bookmarks. I want to create playlists for my YouTube channel with them. Is there any way to do it automatically without having to add each individual URL to a playlist?

Comment: Answer here: [How to create a playlist form a list of links (not from bookmarks)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120451/how-to-create-a-playlist-form-a-list-of-links-not-from-bookmarks)

Comment: @user0 The current question and answer below have dates far earlier than the link you have provided? How is this question a duplicate of the link you have provided if this question has a prior date? shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @jaggi new question with an accepted answer has higher priority than an older unaccepted question (said mods). also, double posting the answer here has no meaning due to the lost interest of OP (OP does not have an account)

Comment: @user0 Don't mods have the power to accept an answer for a question? This question and the provided answer have more upvotes & more activity than the other link. Did you genuinely try to point the OP of your link to this question, before you wrote the answer there which is more or less same as the answer written here?

Comment: @jaggi sure they can I guess but they never do so. as for the rest - I wasn't aware of this post when answering over there back in Sep 2018 and as you can notice this was linked as duplicate just recently (Mar 2019). apologies for my non-awareness.

Answer (score 37):

1. Go to bookmarks manager and select all the YouTube links and copy and paste them in a text file, say `you.list`, and RUN following on your terminal (assuming you use a linux system):

   `grep -o 'v=.*' you.list | cut -f2 -d"="| tr '\n' ','`

   You'll get comma separated list video ids something like:
   `J6PBD-wNEDs,afwPe_OqPX0,OGcG4jSKOVA,hegL0V4ckco,LajAWn51HmE`.
2. Copy these ids and append it to `http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?
   video_ids=`

   You'll get a link similar to this 
    `http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=J6PBD-
     wNEDs,afwPe_OqPX0,OGcG4jSKOVA,hegL0V4ckco,LajAWn51HmE`
3. Open this link in the browser and it'll create an 'untitled playlist', for the above links it would be `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6PBD-wNEDs&list=TLGGDO-k0WVJQ_8yNDA1MjAxNw`
4. Go to the playlist URL for the generated playlist in this format:
   `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=[PLAYLIST ID]&disable_polymer=true`, which for the above example would 
   be `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=TLGGDO-k0WVJQ_8yNDA1MjAxNw&disable_polymer=true`. Press the three dots to the right of the playlist title, and then select "Add all to..." to add the videos to your own playlist. As [@jet-blue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/105476/jet-blue) says, you may need to use the `&disable_polymer=true` URL parameter to see the "Add all to..." drop-down option.

I guess the proper way of doing what the question is asking for is through YouTube developer api. 
`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert#examples`

Reference:`http://cects.com/youtube-playlist/`

Comment: I created the playlists I wanted long ago, but opened your link out of curiosity. It does generate a temporary playlist, but its title ("Untitled list") is not clickable, so there's no way to access the page that would let me save it to my account.

Comment: I have updated the answer. pls look at the changes. I guess YouTube handles the untitled playlists differently. I will post this issue in youtube forums. lets see what I get.

Comment: Your answer is nearly complete. Once you have the untitled playlist open in youtube there is an option to "Copy All into" (dots in the right hand corner gives you this option) whereby you can create a new playlist which will have all those videos in it.

Comment: @CashCow Can you edit the answer to include this info?

Comment: @CashCow I'm not able to see dots option, could you put a screenshot and edit the answer if possible?

Comment: Append `&disable_polymer=true` to the playlist url in order to get access to the `Add all to...` feature.

Comment: @jaggi just some minor details to mention:
- Video ids must be clean from other utms (eg. use Xkj931k not Xkj931k?t=10, which would be a video at specific time)
- Also don't include more than 50 video ids in one url. At this moment, 50 video ids is the maximum that youtube will display in the new untitled playlist. As a turn around you have to create new playlists for every 50 songs you want to add

Comment: @gpelelis good points, thanks for pointing these out.

Comment: @jaggi wow what an amazing hack.. you saved me so much time with your ingenuity!

Comment: As of mid 2020, disable_polymer was only working intermittently. As of the end of 2020, it has stopped working completely. You can still mass add videos from one playlist to another, but the caveat is you have to be the author of both playlists, and these "temporary" playlists that are created by using /watch with multiple IDs appended are not considered to be authored by you, so you can't mass add them to another list. Which really sucks.

Comment: We still can mass add videos from someone's playlist to one of our own, @tubedogg: just replace www with music on the source playlist, and voilà.

Comment: @AndréLevy Thanks for the heads-up. I did try this previously (around the time I added my last comment) but at that point it was not working. Good to see that that option still exists. I have wasted so much time adding things to playlists in my own ways (Python script accessing the API, but only 200 per day because of API limits, and manually in the browser).

Answer (score 2):

A small python script

- to extract all the youtube links from the text file `you.list`.
- open the browser (in background) with all the videos - `urllib2.urlopen(listOfVideos)`.
- gets the new playlist link - `response.geturl()`.
- opens the web browser again to to edit the playlist properties (playListURL) or directly start playing the list  `webbrowser.open(playListURL)`.

*tested on Google Chrome

```
import os, io
import webbrowser
from urllib import request

videos = []
f = open("you.list", 'r')
for line in f:
    videos.append(line.strip())
listOfVideos = "http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=" + ",".join(videos)

response = request.urlopen(listOfVideos)
playListLink = response.geturl().split('list=')[1]

# edit playlist with this URL
playListURL = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=" + playListLink + "&disable_polymer=true"

# or start playing from first to last with this one
playNowURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videos[0] + "&list=" + playListLink

webbrowser.open(playListURL)
```