# How to create a playlist form a list of links (not from bookmarks)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have something like that https://pastebin.com/ssmtZhW2 how do I convert this to a YouTube playlist?

Comment: None of the **answers don't work anymore**. The problem is in converting and saving "Untitled Playlist" to normal one. Untitled Playlist can't be saved anywhere, and the trick with "disable_polymer" doesn't work anymore.

The **only working solution** now, in 2022, is to use extension [Multiselect for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiselect-for-youtube/gpgbiinpmelaihndlegbgfkmnpofgfei) to select all videos and save them to new proper playlist. Thank me later ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

also, you can create it manually if you take this URL and add comma separated IDs:

**1.** **`https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=`** like:

**2.** **`https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=AwyRYse4kss,QoitiIbdeaM,drlB2RT_XiA,etc...`**

**3.** then paste it into the browser's search box and hit **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

**4.** this will create a special playlist URL called "Untitled Playlist" where you will have your videos
**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rL1HcFc-Fg&list=TLGG2e3mUQob0B0wOTA5MjAxOA**

**SIDE NOTE: unfortunately there is one downside... such playlist is limited only to 50 videos**

**5.**  to save such playlist, be sure that you are logged in into youtube

**6.**  add **&disable_polymer=true** at the end of the URL and hit **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**
 

```
https://youtu.be/watch?v=0rL1HcFc-Fg&list=TLGG2e3mUQob0B0wOTA5MjAxOA&disable_polymer=true
```

**7.** then, somewhere around **<kbd>Subscribe</kbd>** button will appear **<kbd>+ Add to</kbd>** button (or 3-dot/3-slash button with plus sign)

[image: 0]

**8.** select **Create a new playlist** name it and press **<kbd>Create</kbd>** button

**9.** done!

Comment: well, I finally tried it and i have problems with saving my playlist. I can't see what you're talking about in step 7 :(

Comment: I agree with @4Lajf.  I can play the videos, but I see no way of saving the playlist.  If I +addTo, only the first video is added.

Comment: @4Lajf https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y4vv.png

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER I don't see the same (maybe because videos are unlisted?)  When I add to a play list, only the current video gets added (so, not very helpful).

Comment: It seem that this method does not work any more. Only one video added.

Comment: In 2022, this doesn't work anymore. You can create an untitled playlist, but you cannot save it.

Comment: Doesn't work. But there is a solution...

Answer (score 2):

there is also an online tool: **http://roll.io/**

```
0rL1HcFc-Fg
NrtklAE0AqQ
zXoKS2FlA8M
ux6UXT2pMhc
0rL1HcFc-Fg
NrtklAE0AqQ
zXoKS2FlA8M
ux6UXT2pMhc
T2RQwSEOplM
DkJ7IzAEDNE
gvtHAhDQAwU
MVD6PeYZm2o
Bnep5nXA8gc
YJNbwCZP40o
vpa7jugmofg
44BJVr17h-g
ezozODdXtHY
eM1o6JJAQs0
foMMNVWPf0o
XlaghBlMico
HDbT34nh4DQ
hGhUNSU0e9M
rqiehBC3d6c
vDgTFuCuD3w
6Gs2_GpXWhc
bP-hDcyUwwY
Ow3rIImBMVE
5S5b3bEdRZA
CZEkMA6FQRQ
esIYXrbpI6M
QMikCPrnIPo
YpJAJLtJnjc
NXXwyR8SJFE
fJnjnaHa2ZE
wGIs69RpxTk
M4-JKvEeYpA
b9VOq9B157I
9JY5bBMj5kw
f52mI1YHp-k
sH0ewuSL4gs
YnD99FSYD30
YET9Djg_AlU
z-sAl3S5qB8
uuzUq3ZeXec
w_GwM8ZwDqQ
c1si206KLoo
mzJqxT1UGho
fD6cZ1A-2fM
SBQprWeOx8g
RUuK0dtYc5U
JRQbVNzmCK0
```

- copy these IDs extracted from URLs and paste it there
- press **<kbd>Run my list!</kbd>** button and you are good to listen

**NOTE:** 50 video limit as well

Comment: Is there anyway to SAVE the playlist?

Comment: @TIXBRANCO using http://roll.io/ no, but you can save it as a bookmark

Comment: Is it me or that site is broken now? It keeps reloading with a default playlist after almost every action

Comment: @DiegoV works well at this side

Comment: Roll.io doesn't load for me. I get an "error 1020 (cloudflare). A google search says that means the firewall is blocking your IP, or country. Some site admins even get this error by the way. Personally I'm not a fan of cloudflare at all. There are numerous examples online of cloudflare screwing things up, blocking sites etc;. I don't care why it happens, I care that it happens. Why people continue to use it I don't understand. /rant

Comment: See https://www.trustpilot.com/review/cloudflare.com.Given all the bad reviews, I'm guessing the good reviews are from cloudflare themselves.

Comment: @jastako This isn't Cloudflare's fault; the site owner has to explicitly configure it to do this in order for this to occur.

Answer (score 2):

Spreadsheet generator is very handy.

There is also a Chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playlist-helper/ibdakohjhchaagmccfedeejmeillongg/related?hl=en) for making playlist out of links.

To save generated playlist, do the following:

1. Scrolling down a little to see the recommended videos on the righthand side.
2. Putting your mouse over one of them, and clicking the "Add to Queue" button.
3. Scrolling back up and clicking the newly made "Add queue to playlist" button.

Answer (score 2):

Here is way by replaying the API call YouTube website is making to add a video in a playlist.
This does not limit number of videos to 50 or anything and does not require any external tool.

- Open one of the videos you want to add and create a new playlist by manually adding this video to it.
- Go to another video you want to add and open network tab of browser developer tools.
- Again add this video to playlist while keeping the network tab open.
- Pick out the network request responsible for adding the video in playlist.
  (for me it was a POST request to https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/browse/edit_playlist?......)
- copy that request as a curl command by right clicking on it.
- There should be ID of the 2nd video in the curl command.(by ID I mean the random string that comes after v= in the video link)
- Now we want to execute this curl request for every ID we have. This can be done using many ways but I chose xargs command to do it.

something like following:

```
grep -o 'v=.*' videolist.txt | cut -f2 -d"=" | xargs -I {#} <copied_curl_command_with_video_ID_substituted_by "{#}">
```

The API call and so the curl command can change with time. note that the curl command contains bunch of identifiers and parameters which helps YouTube to identify you when adding videos to your playlist. which means it should expire after sometime.

Answer (score 1):

**SPREADSHEET YOUTUBE PLAYLIST GENERATOR:**

here I wrote a simple spreadsheet playlist generator: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8Jjx1Db2Bacv7iXozNQ1gG3hBVtk7Xmo1WvZ9GtU9g/edit#gid=1950325992)**
just add youtube links in any desired order and press that red text in cell **B1** to play it.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't let me add a url or am I missing something.

Comment: @TIXBRANCO make a copy. **File > Make copy**

Comment: Thanks I did.  It works great.  I made a shared  spreadsheet for a group I'm in.  Would you like any social proof or acknowledgement, if so PM me a link that I can promote to the group.  I did note that the playlist link generated  from the spreadsheet does not work the same way one of your own playlists work if you put it in one of the playlist conversion websites.  I was messing with that so my group could copy the list but that doesn't seem possible with what I've tried so far.

Comment: This is great! (1) Does this also run into the 50 max limit? (2) What's the difference between "PLAYLIST" and "CC PLAYLIST"?

Comment: This is cool, but it doesn't answer the question - how to take a list of URLs and create a youtube playlist.  Your tool seems to take some kind of existing Youtube playlist HTML source and massage it into an URL.  On sheet 4 there's an auto-populated list of URLs.  If that list is removed and replaced with the desired list, the sheet with the red play button doesn't update, sadly.  Maybe you could update it to follow changes to S4.

Answer (score 1):

A small python script

- to extract all the youtube links from the text file `you.list`.
- open the browser (in background) with all the videos - `urllib2.urlopen(listOfVideos)`.
- gets the new playlist link - `response.geturl()`.
- opens the web browser again to allow the user to edit the playlist properties  `webbrowser.open(playListURL)`.

*tested on Google Chrome

```
import os, io
import webbrowser
import urllib2

inputFileName = 'you.list'

def ReadMultipleDataFrom(thisTextFile, thisPattern):
    inputData = []
    file = open(thisTextFile, "r")
    for iLine in file:
        if iLine.startswith(thisPattern):
            iLine = iLine.rstrip()
            # print iLine
        if ('v=') in iLine: # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBcDeFGH
            iLink = iLine.split('v=')[1]
            inputData.append(iLink) 
        if ('be/') in iLine: # https://youtu.be/aBcDeFGH
            iLink =  iLine.split('be/')[1]
            inputData.append(iLink)
    return inputData

videoLinks =  ReadMultipleDataFrom(inputFileName, "https")              
# print videoLinks

listOfVideos = "http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=" + ','.join(videoLinks)
# print listOfVideos

response = urllib2.urlopen(listOfVideos)
playListLink = response.geturl()
# print playListLink

playListLink = playListLink.split('list=')[1]
# print playListLink

playListURL = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list="+playListLink+"&disable_polymer=true"
webbrowser.open(playListURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every answer mentioned here is able to create a limited list of 50 videos.

I have found a Chrome extension [Multiselect for YouTube™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiselect-for-youtube/gpgbiinpmelaihndlegbgfkmnpofgfei). It allows multiselection of videos everywhere. And you can perform actions like

- Add to Queue
- Add to playlist
  etc.

Here is the result I just created [Dr. Israr Ahmad Backup](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlHilqUR1hQOwwJ16eOyzEMywC_ocwXBK), a playlist of every video of a channel.

Comment: Can this extension convert a list of URLs to a playlist? It seems like I must instead manually check each video?