# Is it still possible to add all the videos from a unlisted YouTube playlist to a listed playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Here is the thread to the answer [How to create a YouTube playlist from a list of links?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/72787/how-to-create-a-youtube-playlist-from-a-list-of-links) JetBlue said it is possible, but when I do it by adding `&disable_polymer=true` to the playlist URL I don't get an option to add all.

Comment: yes, it's possible: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120454/186471

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a playlist form a list of links (not from bookmarks)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120451/how-to-create-a-playlist-form-a-list-of-links-not-from-bookmarks)