# Recreate a youtube playlist from a mhtml file

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I've been adding music to my playlist for a long time and back it up often to a mhtml file, it has all the details of the normal playlist page and even has the urls of the songs when you click on them, recently the playlist got jumbled up and i cannot revert it, is there a way to grab/move all the songs from the file onto a new playlist?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/72787/how-to-create-a-youtube-playlist-from-a-list-of-links